# matching dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

How to check dictionary d1 is exist in d2 in python?

```
d1 = {u'from':{u'dn':'topology/pod-1/node-101'}}
d2 = {u'faults': [{u'count': 1, u'pos': {u'y': 339, u'x': 860}, u'level': u'critical'}], u'from': {u'dn': u'topology/pod-1/node-101', u'type': u'leaf'}, u'to': {u'dn': u'topology/pod-1/node-104', u'type': u'spine'}}
```

Comment: `d1 is exist in d2` - What do you mean by that?

Comment: may OP talking about key and its value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging essentially from the OP's *example* (as the English text is mysterious), I'd say...:

- `d1` is a `dict` whose keys are Unicode and values are `dict`s
- `d2` is a `dict` whose keys are Unicode and values are `list`s or `dict`s

and the task is: verify if every key `k` of `d1` is also a key of `d2` with a `dict` value; and `d1[k]` is a "sub-dictionary" of `d2[k]` (every key of the former is also a key of the latter with identical value).

Of course that's a **lot** of interpretation so I'll code it out in elementary terms for ease of likely-needed future tweaks:-)

```
def d1_in_d2(d1, d2):
    for k in d1:
        if k not in d2: return False
        v2 = d2[k]
        if not isinstance(v2, dict): return False
        v1 = d1[k]
        for kk in v1:
            if kk not in v2: return False
            if v1[kk] != v2[kk]: return False
    return True
```

What say you, OP?  Once this matches your desired semantics it can be simplified, compacted, optimized -- but let's apply the grand old maxim of "first, make it work":-)

Comment: I was actually thinking of using recursion to solve it, but assuming that his dictionaries are only 1 level deep, this works very well. +1

Comment: @Shashank, required recursion **might** be among the several ways in which the OP's mysterious specs could differ from the simple ones I reverse-engineered from his example -- let's wait and see if and how the OP clarifies the now-mysterious specs!-)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `dict1` if a subset of `dict2` doing this:

```
all(item in d2.items() for item in d1.items())
```

Comment: it always return False, since d1 is only partial in d2, for example: d1=u'from': {u'dn': u'topology/pod-1/node-101', u'type': u'leaf'}, but d2 has extra keys in it d2 has = u'from': {u'dn': u'topology/pod-1/node-101', u'type': u'leaf'}

Comment: @HiepNguyen So basically what you're asking for is a *recursive* subset. Where you recurse to compare the values if they are also dicts?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate it and check if it exists.

```
d1 = dict.items()
d2 = dict.items()

for values in d1:
    if values in d2:
        print values, " is in dict"
```